# How to interrupt a curl upload in php?

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4

I've created a php script to handle uploads and I'm trying to return an error immediately in case of an error (e.g. the file already exists).

Unfortunately, according to my tests, although I return immediately, curl will continue uploading the entire file until it ends:

```
public function uploadFile($filename) {
    Log::info('Uploading file...' . $filename);
    register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, "streamInterrupted"));
    $this->bytes_transferred=0;
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(false);       
    $path = Config::get('agent.files_root'). '/' . $filename;
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        /*
         * yes, I know, this needs to be worked on 
         * as it would allow a malicious user to find out
         * if a file exists on the server...
         */         
        Log::error('Oops, the file already exists! ' . $filename);
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'That file already exists.'),
            400
        );
    }
    $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
    /* Open a file for writing */
    $fp = fopen($path, "w");

    /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
       and write to the file */
    while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
      fwrite($fp, $data);

    /* Close the streams */
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($putdata);
    Log::info('Yay! The file was uploaded successfully! ' . $filename);
    return Response::json(array(
            'error' => false,
            'message' => 'The file was uploaded successfully!'),
            400
        );  
}
```

So, as you can see, before I even start reading the PUT data, I verify if the file exists and return an error immediately (by the way, I can see the test is being triggered successfully) but curl won't give up until it finishes pushing all its data.

Is there a way I can cleanly interrupt it? I'm fairly certain I could just die() but then I wouldn't be able to push a status code and error message back to the client...

Any thoughts?

Thank you,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can interrupt an upload client connection:

```
// return bad request immediately...
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
// generate error message
$message=json_encode(array(
                     'error'=>true,
                     'message'=>'That file already exists.'));
return header('Content-length: ' . strlen($message)) . $message;
```

The main thing was reporting a content-length so, if you simply want to kill the connection you can:

```
header('Content-length: 0');
```

But because I wanted to return a message, I made sure the content-length was the size of the message and returned it after pushing the header.